Django error: Reverse for 'user_workouts' not found. 'user_workouts' is not a valid view function or pattern name
I'm working on my project for a course and I'm totally stuck right now. I'm creating a website to manage workouts by user and the create workout do not redirect to the user's workouts page when I create the new workout instance.
views.py
# View to return all user's workouts
def user_workouts(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    print(user)
    workouts = get_list_or_404(Workout, user=user.id)
    return render(request, "users/workouts.html", {"user": user, "workouts": workouts})


# Create workout view

def add_workout(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    print(user)
    print(request._post)
    if request.method == "POST":
        workout_title = request.POST.get("workout")
        reps = request.POST.get("reps")
        load = request.POST.get("load")
        last_update = request.POST.get("last_update")
        workout = Workout(workout=workout_title, reps=reps, load=load, last_update=last_update,      user=user)
        workout.save()
        print(user.id)
        return redirect('user_workouts')
    context = {"workout": workout}
    return render(request, "users/add_workout.html", context=context)

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "myapp"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>", views.user_detail, name="user_detail"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>/workouts", views.user_workouts, name="user_workouts"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>/workouts/<int:workout_id>", views.workout_detail, name="workout_detail"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>/workouts/Add Workout", views.open_workout_form, name="open_workout_form"),
    path("user/<int:user_id>/workouts/create/", views.add_workout, name="add_workout")
]


You specified an app_name = … [Django-doc], so it is:
return redirect('myapp:user_workouts')
